# Find the word in a sentence with maximum specific character count

Tags: php, regex

I am new to PHP Development and finally with the help of SO I am able to write a program for finding word in a sentence with maximum specific character count.

Below is what I have tried:

```
<?php
// Program to find the word in a sentence with maximum specific character count
// Example: "O Romeo, Romeo, wherefore art thou Romeo?”
// Solution: wherefore 
// Explanation: Because "e" came three times
$content = file_get_contents($argv[1]); // Reading content of file
$max = 0;
$arr = explode(" ", $content); // entire array of strings with file contents
for($x =0; $x<count($arr); $x++) // looping through entire array 
{
$array[$x] = str_split($arr[$x]); // converting each of the string into array
}
for($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++)
{
    $count = array_count_values($array[$x]);
    $curr_max = max($count);
    if($curr_max > $max)
    {
        $max = $curr_max;
        $word = $arr[$x];
    }
}
echo $word;
?>
```

Question: Since I am new to PHP development I don't know the optimization techniques. Is there anyway I can optimize this code? Also, Can I use regex to optimize this code further? Kindly guide.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "specific character count"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. another example: "abc abbc eeea" . So the answer will be "eeea" as e comes three times. I don't know how can I rephrase the question

Comment: use `foreach` instead of `for` loops. Use `preg_split` to split the string on non-letter characters. Use `count_chars` with eventually `strtolower`

Answer (score 1):

I love coding this type of mini-challenges in the minimum lines of code :D. So here is my solution:

```
function wordsWithMaxCharFrequency($sentence) {

    $words = preg_split('/\s+/', $sentence);

    $maxCharsFrequency = array_map (function($word) {
        return max(count_chars(strtolower($word)));
    }, $words);

    return array_map(function($index) use($words) {
        return $words[$index];
    }, array_keys($maxCharsFrequency, max($maxCharsFrequency)));
}

print_r(wordsWithMaxCharFrequency("eeee yyyy"));
//Output: Array ( [0] => eeee [1] => yyyy )

print_r(wordsWithMaxCharFrequency("xx llll x"));
//Output: Array ( [0] => llll )
```

**Update1:**

If you want to get only `A-Za-z` words use the following code:

```
$matches = [];
//a word is either followed by a space or end of input
preg_match_all('/([a-z]+)(?=\s|$)/i', $sentence, $matches); 
$words = $matches[1];
```

Just a contribution that could inspire you :D!

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you kindly tell me if I just want to have A-Z and a-z into the consideration then how can I neglect rest of the character while reading the file content using `file_get_contents`

Comment: if file has `" aa bbb e????"` my answer should be `b` and `not the question mark`.

Comment: I understand, please check my answer Update1.